# PDE Books w/ Solutions - Recommendation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

My question is simple. I'm an undergraduate student taking Partial Differential Equations. I'm looking for a problem book with solutions.

My intent is to just do problem after problem to practice for my final and our assigned PDE book doesn't have the answers, so there's no way of checking.

Would anyone happen to know of a good PDE book that has problems and answers (or if possible a solution manual) that I can find online?

The book we're currently using is: Basic Partial Differential Equations by David Bleecker and George Csordas.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Elements Of Partial Differential Equation by Ian.Sneddon is a nice book on pde with plenty of solved examples.

Comment: Yes it is indeed good but it needs an instructor also. :-)