# books recommendations for discrete pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graph-theory, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, network

I am a beginner of discrete PDE (PDE on graph)!
Is there any book for discrete PDE which specifies the concept of differentiation and integration, laplacian and solving hyperbolic, parabolic, elliptic equations on graph?
Thank you for every suggestions and comments!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715071/pde-books-w-solutions-recommendation?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange, @chocoblossom!  Could you clarify a little bit what your background is (especially wrt PDE) and also what your goal is?

Comment: My initial reaction is that a book on Finite difference methods would be a good place to start, since they often cover discrete-in-space, continuous-in-time problems.  This may not fit your needs, however. . .

Comment: @Strants Thank you! I have a brief background for partial differential equation since I learned it in my graduate course and I try to start the graph theory. My goal is to estimate a form of dispersion on network to analysis advertisement effect of a firm.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Thank you:)